# How to print this unicode line using one string?

Tags: c++

I'm having problems with a specific Unicode character.

Let's say I want to print out Október:
ó=U+00F3

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
cout << "\xF3"; //this prints ó
cout << "Okt\xF3"; //this prints Októ
cout << "Okt\xF3ber"; //this prints Oktľr
```

The only way I know to print out Október is:

```
cout << Okt\xF3 << ber;
```

How do I create a sting that prints Október?

Comment: What about `"Okt\u00F3ber"` or simply `"Október"` (if your compiler + source file format supports it)?

Comment: @DyP: `\u00F3be` is a valid sequence.  The spec: "There is no limit to the number of digits in a hexadecimal sequence."

Comment: @DyP:"Október" will be just as bad as mine, except if read from a file, that's kind of weird.

Comment: @RichieHindle AFAIK that's true for the hexadecimal escape sequence (`\x`) but _not_ for the universal-character-names (hex-quads for `\u`).

Comment: @DyP: Ah, sorry, missed that distinction!  Time to get some sleep.  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use compile-time string concatenation to prevent the escape sequence going further than you wanted:

```
cout << "Okt\xF3" "ber";
```

Comment: If only there were, like, `\&` escape sequence to stand for no character, so that `'\&a'` would mean `'a'` and `"Okt\xF3\&ber"` would mean `"Október"`.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
cout << "Okt\xF3\x62\x65r";
```

A hexadecimal escape sequence extends as far as possible, so the `'b'` and `'e'`, which are valid hexadecimal digits are included in the escape sequence.